# pandas pd.ExcelWriter and xlrd to output python dataframe as excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I can print a dataframe using display (and it shows and it's correct), but when I output the same dataframe to a excel file I can't find the file?

My code is:

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import xlrd
import openpyxl

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('workbook_name.xlsx')
merged_data.to_excel(writer,'sheet_name')
```

Comment: Since you didn't specify a different path -- i.e. you just specified the filename -- the file is being saved to the directory as shown by: `import os; os.getcwd()`

Comment: Thanks Bernie! I found the file in the default directory after I used the save command.

Comment: Try omitting the writer line and giving a full path string as the first argument to .to_excel. That should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

The Excel file output by the excelwriter command will appear in the same directory as the python file or ipython notebook (.ipynb).

To save the file you need to use the **Save** Command.

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import xlrd
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('workbook_name.xlsx') #creates instance of an excel workbook
merged_data.to_excel(writer,'worksheet_name') #creates workbook 
writer.save() #saves workbook to file in python file directory
```

**Dependencies required**

- pandas
- openpyxl
- xlrd